# Is it possible to Debug JSX variables in chrome debugger when developing in React?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, jsx

I want to check the value of variables in my **JSX** files while debugging with chrome debugger, as it is done in js files.

I've created the app using [Create-React-App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app)

When using JSX files, I can get the value of variables in the command tab when I type the name of the variable, but in the source tab, when debugger hits a breakpoint, when I hover on variables, the chrome won't show the value, while the hovering shows the variable value in js files (The picture below)
[JSX file in Chrome Source Tab, All Black with no Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqikm.png)

I would like to know the values in chrome debugger by hovering over them, like JS files.

[js files debugging in chrome source tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw7FK.png)

Do I have to change the `WebPack` settings to generate source maps?

Comment: This is quite hard has the JSX files injected into chrome and translated into html and proper JS. Nevertheless is an interesting topic I will deep into and give you an answer asap